# How do I automate file permission on files transferred from Windows to AIX to inherit AIX Directory Permissions

Tags: permissions, aix

I have two applications, one hosted on Windows and the other in AIX and what I need is to transfer files created in the Windows application directly to a directory in AIX where it can be picked up and interfaced by the application hosted on AIX. During testing we found that files copied into the AIX directory do not automatically inherit the permissions of the directory it is copied into and thus we have to manually change the permissions in order for the AIX application to capture the file and process it.

I am not very familiar with AIX so I I asked our AIX Server admin for help however the response was that I have to create a script to do this for me.Is there a way to automate changing the file permissions to that of the directory the file is being placed in without a script?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but wouldn't using [Samba on AIX](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix_samba/) simplify things? This way, you can access a Windows network drive from AIX.

Comment: Permissions (r/w/x) or owner/user?

Comment: It would help if you could provide some more context information how the transfer is currently implemented in particular, e.g. are you using scp, sftp or similar, or mounting a CIFS share on the AIX server, or mounting an NFS share on the windows server and in what user context does the transfer run.